# ImageMagick miscalculates height when drawing text

Tags: imagemagick, diacritics

When drawing text using ImageMagick 6.7.3-1 (2011-10-21 Q16), the result is cropped at the topline if i use large German characters that contain so-called "Umlaute".

[image: see the problem here]

```
/opt/local/bin/convert -background "rgba(255,255,255,0)" -fill "#878787" -font tfonts/MyriadPro-BlackSemiCn.ttf -pointsize 60 label:"TESTING GERMAN UMLAUTE Ä Ö Ü" "img/dyn/s-19.0.7.png"
```

Is there a way i could easily fix this?

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

Version: ImageMagick 6.7.3-4 2011-11-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

and default font everything is fine.

So quick fix would be either to update ImageMagic or to pick different font.

Comment: Thank you, Roman B. I'm afraid i am bound to both, the version and the font. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could specify the size -size XxY

Comment: Yes, but can i be sure that the size will always be the pointsize + XY pixels?

Comment: That's true. No ideas anymore, sorry.